# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors In addition: Warning message: Unknown or uninitialised column: `caption`

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a summerizing table and this is my code. I can upload the database just in case, if it should help to recognize the problem.
The errors are many and I can't get rid of them...in the end the table doesn't show up and I get a blank MSword page.

```
fit <- mle2(
  Correct  ~ dbinom(size = 10, prob = rep(c(pAE, pBD), each = 23)),
  start = list(pAE = 0.5, pBD = 0.5),
  data = wasps
)
table3 <- wasps %>% group_by(Colors) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>%
  bind_cols(Estimate = coef(fit), SE = stdEr(fit), confint(fit))
tabledoc <- file.choose()
read_docx(tabledoc) %>%
  body_add_par("\n") %>%
  body_add_par(
    paste("Table 3: Proportion of correct choices made Polistes dominula paper wasps during 
transitive inference trials with unfamiliar stimuli (CIs using likelihood profile).\n")
  ) %>%
  body_add_flextable(table3) %>%
  body_add_par("\n") %>%
  print(tabledoc)
shell.exec(tabledoc)
```

This is the output:

```
> fit <- mle2(
+   Correct  ~ dbinom(size = 10, prob = rep(c(pAE, pBD), each = 23)),
+   start = list(pAE = 0.5, pBD = 0.5),
+   data = wasps
+ )
Warning messages:
1: In dbinom(x = c(3L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L,  :
  NaNs produced
2: In dbinom(x = c(3L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L,  :
  NaNs produced
3: In dbinom(x = c(3L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L,  :
  NaNs produced
4: In dbinom(x = c(3L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L,  :
  NaNs produced
5: In dbinom(x = c(3L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L,  :
  NaNs produced
6: In dbinom(x = c(3L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L,  :
  NaNs produced
> table3 <- wasps %>% group_by(Colors) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>%
+   bind_cols(Estimate = coef(fit), SE = stdEr(fit), confint(fit))
Profiling...

> tabledoc <- file.choose()
> read_docx(tabledoc) %>%
+   body_add_par("\n") %>%
+   body_add_par(
+     paste("Table 3: Proportion of correct choices made Polistes dominula paper wasps during 
transitive inference trials with unfamiliar stimuli (CIs using likelihood profile).\n")
+   ) %>%
+   body_add_flextable(table3) %>%
+   body_add_par("\n") %>%
+   print(tabledoc)
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `caption`.
```

Comment: It seems strange to have the `file.choose()` inside a non-interactive markdown document. Maybe try putting the file path in to see if that's the problem.

Comment: Using file.choose() allows me to select an empty .docx file where to write my table. I used it for other parts in the same code and worked...